# Apply default full writes permission when creating new folder

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora, network-shares

We are facing issues of permissions. scenario is

We have Federoa with Xammp server running and shared project directory for local network to create project folders for project development. Everything is good except one thing that when we create new folder on network it does not have full rights but **"drwxr-xr-x"** and due to this our PHP program cannot upload files. It is all about insufficient rights permissions.

Before this Fedora installation, previous one was working perfectly fine. That we were able to create folders which were having default full permissions rights to do anything.

**Commands and Results**:

```
[root@umi]# setfacl -R -d -m g::rwx -m u::rwx -m o::rwx ajax_upload
[root@umi]# getfacl ajax_upload
# file: ajax_upload
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::rwx
```

Then I created a directory inside ajax_upload directory from windows platform on network sharing named "test2"

```
[root@umi]# getfacl ajax_upload/test2
# file: ajax_upload/test2
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::rwx
```

You see "group::r-x" and "other::r-x"... below is ls -ld results

```
[root@umi]# ls -ld ajax_upload/test2
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 root root 4096 2014-06-27 11:29 ajax_upload/test2
```

Can anyone suggest what we do that when we create new folder it must have full rights like **"drwxrwxrwx"**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mount your filesystem with `acl` support (i.e. /etc/fstab has acl in the options [4th] field for that filesystem), you can use the `setfacl` command to set default permissions for newly created files and directories:

`setfacl -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rwx /target/directory`

Now when any user creates directories inside of `/target/directory/`, those new dirs will be created with "drwxrwxrwx+" permissions.  The + means that acls are present and can be shown with the `getfacl` command.

Of course, you'll want to make sure that /target/directory itself is writable by your users.

Comment: Our concern is not to create directories using commend line which we know that we can change permissions using CHMOD command... while we need to have it set for, when we create folder on network using windows platform... as described: we have "projects" folder shared from Linux and on windows we create folder in projects folder and here new created folder needs to have full permission. I tried to set umask 000 but it also did not work. Any suggestion?

Comment: @UMI I understand that chmod isn't sufficient and that's why I didn't suggest it.  Did you try the setfacl command?

Comment: Do you mean that if I run command "setfacl -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rwx /projects" then creating new directories will have full rights permissions? I you say yes then I give it try now.. waiting for your response

Comment: Yep, the -d sets that as the default permissions for new entries in that dir.

Comment: Thank you for your response and I have strong feeling that it can resolve the issue but now after a test I have small issue remaining that this command sets rights "drwxr-xr-x+" while I need "drwxrwxrwx". Can you alter your command line so that I got my required rights please?

Comment: Because I did test that when after this command I have such rights, does not allow to write something. Still needs full rights, as you can see we have "drwxr-xr-x+" after creating new directory inside the directory on which I ran that command.

Comment: Any suggestion to make changes in your command to get it worked please?

Comment: Edited question for you :) Now let's see what your response will be!

Comment: That might be a special case for root... what's it look like when a non-root user creates a dir in there?

Comment: I know this is correct answer and I have some rare case that it is not working but I have strong feeling that it is the solutions. Thank you for your time TheAmigo!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `mkdir` (I'm guessing that is what you are using now), try using:

```
install -d -m 0777 /new/dir/
```

That will create a new dir called `/new/dir/` with full permissions (like `chmod 777`).

The other solution is to use proper `umask` values for the user creating the directories.  Please review [**this thread**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84790/set-default-permisson-for-newly-folders-and-files-in-linux) for more info and an example.

---

After reading your comments, I'm pretty sure the problem is with your current values for `umask`.  Please read the following threads, to make sure you have the right settings in there - if not, make some changes and try again:

- [Linux directory permission inheritance for new files created](https://superuser.com/questions/681693/linux-directory-permission-inheritance-for-new-files-created)
- [How to setup nfs share for users with write permissions](https://superuser.com/questions/747940/how-to-setup-nfs-share-for-users-with-write-permissions?rq=1)

Comment: Our concern is not to create directories using commend line which we know that we can change permissions using CHMOD command... while we need to have it set for, when we create folder on network using windows platform... as described: we have "projects" folder shared from Linux and on windows we create folder in projects folder and here new created folder needs to have full permission. I tried to set umask 000 but it also did not work. Any suggestion?

Comment: oh ok, that's not in your problem's description.  Can you provide the details on how the directories were shared in the first place?  Edit your question with those details, please... "We have Fedora with Xammp server running and shared project directory for local network to create project folders for project development" it's a bit vague, considering your previous comment.  Let's see if we can came up with something after getting more details :)

Comment: please check first comment to your answer in which elaborated the scenario.

Comment: I have updated my question... let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope this helps :)